# Paste text as summary?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is there any way to paste a chunk of copied text as summary?
For example when the clipboard has a chunk of text and in VS editor I paste the text after the X, everything is not prepended with ///. Is there any way to prepend every line with ///?

```
/// <summary>
///   X
/// </summary>
void foo(void) {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly the response you want, but you can paste your lines and then select with ALT-CLICK (column mode) the left part of the new lines inserted and press "/" three times. It is what I'm doing.

Maybe faster : paste the text, select it, CTRL-K + CTRL-C two times. You will get four '/'. Then ALT-CLICK to select the first column of '/' and press delete. :)